# mod_auth_openidc - OIDCSessionInactivityTimeout not working - 401

Tags: session, timeout, openid, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

I have the OIDCSessionInactivityTimeout set in auth_openidc.conf.

When the inactivity timeout hits, subsequent calls return a 401. If I refresh the page, my session is back to normal and all calls go through.

I'm not being redirected back to the OP for re-authentication when the inactivity timeout hits.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here (another setting in conf?).